# Adding HTML to an XElement

Tags: c#, xml, linq

Im using the classes in System.Linq.Xml to build up an XML object. But the API I am working with require me to put straight HTML code into a tag:

```
<message><html><body>...</body></html></message>
```

I cant seem to figure out how to do this using XElement.

```
new XElement("message", myHtmlStringVariable);
```

That just escapes all the HTML characters

```
new XElement("message", new XCData(myHtmlStringVariable));
```

That wraps the HTML in a `<![CDATA[`...`]]>` which the API doesnt like.

So is there a way to insert HTML directly into an XElement's content?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do this:

```
string html = "<html><body></body></html>";
XElement message = new XElement("message", XElement.Parse(html));
```

This does require that the HTML is well-formed XML and has only a single root element.

If you have an HTML snippet with multiple root elements, you can always create the element like this:

```
string html = "<p>foo</p><p>bar</p>";
XElement message = XElement.Parse("<message>" + html + "</message>");
```

The requirement for well-formed XML still exists. This means you must have empty elements like `<br />` and not `<br>`. There is no way around that if you want to embed HTML directly in XML.

Additionally, if it's possible and your API accepts it, I would recommend giving the HTML elements the proper XHTML namespace:

```
string html = "<html xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\"><body></body></html>";
XElement message = new XElement("message", XElement.Parse(html));
```

This produces XML like this:

```xml
<message>
  <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <body></body>
  </html>
</message>
```

Comment: Awesome, I'll test it out. Just wondering though, what would happen if the HTML is not well formed?

Comment: OK, so it crashes if you dont have the HTML as valid XML... just something to watch out for I guess.

Comment: @d1k_is: It throws an `XmlException` if it's not well formed, so you could catch that. Unfortunately there isn't a `TryParse` method as far as I'm aware.

Answer (score 3):

```
new XElement("message", new XRaw(myHtmlStringVariable));

public class XRaw : XText
{
  public XRaw(string text):base(text){}
  public XRaw(XText text): base(text){}

  public override void WriteTo(System.Xml.XmlWriter writer)
  {
    writer.WriteRaw(this.Value);
  }
}
```

Comment: Just be carefull that this code will fail:
var xraw = new XRaw("<br />");
new XElement("message", xraw, xraw);

It does not seem to handle usage of a XRaw object more than once(WriteTo is just called once).